# Ciclo For para child rows datatables

Tags: jquery, html, datatables

[image: Ejemplo De Imagen]
Tengo este ejemplo tomado de `Datatables` el cual requiero, si bien este ejemplo al oprimir cierto boton muestra un poco mas de informacion de lo que hay en esa fila.

Pero en mi caso requiero que con el id de esa fila haga un envio por ajax y en el `.done` haga un ciclo for que me muestre todas las calificaciones que tiene un estudiante.

**CODIGO DE DATABLES**

```
// Add event listener for opening and closing details
    $('#example tbody').on('click', 'td.details-control', function () {
        var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
        var row = table.row( tr );

        if ( row.child.isShown() ) {
            // This row is already open - close it
            row.child.hide();
            tr.removeClass('shown');
        }
        else {
            // Open this row
            row.child( format(row.data()) ).show();
            tr.addClass('shown');
        }
    } );
```

```
 function format ( d ) {
    // `d` is the original data object for the row
    return '<table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="padding-left:50px;">'+
        '<tr>'+
            '<td>Full name:</td>'+
            '<td>'+d.name+'</td>'+
        '</tr>'+
        '<tr>'+
            '<td>Extension number:</td>'+
            '<td>'+d.extn+'</td>'+
        '</tr>'+
        '<tr>'+
            '<td>Extra info:</td>'+
            '<td>And any further details here (images etc)...</td>'+
        '</tr>'+
    '</table>';
}
```

La funcion `format(d)` recibe el dato y y retorna ese dato en una vista creada una pequeña tabla que en pocas palabras seria el `child.rows()`

Si en esa funcion tomo ese dato e implemento un ajax la funcion nunca me va a mostrar las operaciones que he realizo en el .done que es necesariamente un ciclo for, sino que me va a mostrar todo lo que `return` fuera del ajax.

Espero haberme hecho entender y que si hay la posibilidad de hacer un `ajax` y realizar un `for` por los datos recibidos que son las calificaciónes por estudiante seria de gran ayuda.

Comment: Estas haciendo la llamada al Ajax con `async = false` ? intenta con eso para que obligue a esperar el resultado.

Comment: tengo el mismo problema y no e podido solucionar no logro retorna la tabla con la respuesta del ajax, alguien lo pudo aplicar al cien?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Intenta poner `Async = false` en la llamada a `ajax`.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var table = $('#example').DataTable({
    "data": data,
    "columns": [{
      "className": 'details-control',
      "orderable": false,
      "data": null,
      "defaultContent": ''
    }, {
      "data": "matricula"
    }, {
      "data": "nombre"
    }, {
      "data": "aula"
    }, {
      "data": "grado"
    }],
    "order": [
      [1, 'asc']
    ]
  });

  // Add event listener for opening and closing details
  $('#example tbody').on('click', 'td.details-control', function() {
    var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
    var row = table.row(tr);

    if (row.child.isShown()) {
      // This row is already open - close it
      row.child.hide();
      tr.removeClass('shown');
    } else {
      // Open this row
      row.child(format(row.data())).show();
      tr.addClass('shown');
    }
  });

});

/* Formatting function for row details - modify as you need */
function format(d) {
  // `d` is the original data object for the row
  return '<table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="padding-left:50px;">' +
    '<tr>' +
    '<td>Calificación:</td>' +
    '<td>' + ObtenerCalificacion(d.matricula) + '</td>' +
    '</tr>' +
    '</table>';
}


//Aqui tendrias que poner tu ajax y calculos
function ObtenerCalificacion(matricula) {
  var calif=matricula;
  /*
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    async: false, //Esta linea tendrias que poner
    data: {
     matricula: matricula
    },
    url: "UrlDedondeseobtiene.loquesa",
    success: function(data) {
      console.log("data", data);
      calif=data.calif;
    },
    error: function(objXMLHttpRequest) {
      console.log("error", objXMLHttpRequest);
    }
  });
  */
  return calif;
}

//Datos de ejemplo
var data = [{
  "matricula": "1",
  "nombre": "Alumno 1",
  "aula": "A",
  "grado": "1",
}, {
  "matricula": "2",
  "nombre": "Alumno 2",
  "aula": "A",
  "grado": "1",
}, {
  "matricula": "3",
  "nombre": "Alumno 3",
  "aula": "A",
  "grado": "1",
}, {
  "matricula": "4",
  "nombre": "Alumno 4",
  "aula": "A",
  "grado": "1",
}, ];
```

```css
td.details-control {
  background: url('https://datatables.net/examples/resources/details_open.png') no-repeat center center;
  cursor: pointer;
}
tr.shown td.details-control {
  background: url('https://datatables.net/examples/resources/details_close.png') no-repeat center center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.13/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.13/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th></th>
      <th>Matricula</th>
      <th>Nombre</th>
      <th>Aula</th>
      <th>Grado</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

</table>
```

Comment: excelente gracias por tu respuesta.

Comment: Si tienes alguna otra duda con mucho gusto te puedo apoyar, saludos.

Comment: ok muchas gracias...ya que me das esa oportunidad no se si depronto me puedas colaborar con una sentencia SQL que he desarrollado pero no me ha funcionado y que inclusive he publicado pero nadie me diio una respuesta concreta. si es asi te agradeceria.

Comment: Claro, pasame el link de la pregunta o mandame un mail cristina.carrasco.angulo@gmail.com

Comment: http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/45718/sentencia-sql-no-arroja-los-datos-necesarios...espero puedas entender y cualquier cosa te envio un correo o me dices, quedo atento.