# Sentencia SQL No Arroja Los Datos Necesarios

Tags: postgresql

Tengo una sentencia que no me funciona de la manera correcta, 

**Áreas de la medicina:**

- Análisis clínicos.
- Anatomía patológica.
- Elemento de lista.
- Anestesiaría y reanimación, entre otras.

lo que necesito es que me seleccione el.

> ID de la especialidad(1) y el nombre de la especialidad`(medicina)` y
>   así mismo que me cuente la cantidad de áreas`(Análisis clínicos)`, 
>   donde las áreas estén `activas` y hayan estudiantes.

Es Decir;  un área puede estar activa pero sin estudiantes (que es la parte que no me interesa tener).

**CÓDIGO**

```
    SELECT 
      especialidad.especialidad_id,
      especialidad.especialidad_descripcion,
      COUNT(areas.*) AS cant,
    FROM
      especialidad
    INNER JOIN area ON (especialidad.especialidad_id = area_id)
    INNER JOIN estudiantes ON (area_id = estudiantes.estudiantes_id)
    WHERE
      area_estado_id = 1 ->(activa)<-
    GROUP BY
especialidad.especialidad_descripción.
```

Este código me muestra las especialidades y me cuentas las áreas que están activas asi hayan o no estudiantes matriculados en el area.

Para tener la idea mas clara este es mi error;

**ESPECIALIDAD | CANTIDAD_DE_AREAS**

MEDICINA        |  2

INGENIERIA IND.   |     7

INGENIERIA INF.  |   3

**IMPORTANTE:**
En este caso MEDICINA tiene 2 areas la  `Análisis clínicos` y  `Anatomía patológica.`; para  `Análisis clínicos` hay 50 matriculas y esta activa pero para `Anatomía patológica.` hay 0 pero esta activa; en ese caso entonces deberia de mostrarme en la cantidad solo 1.

**ESTRUCTURA DE LAS TABLAS:**

**especialidad**

- especialidad_id
- especialidad_descripcion

**area**

- area_id
- area_descripcion
- area_estado
- area_id_especialidad
- estudiante_id

**matriculados**

- matriculados_id
- area_id
- estudiante_id
- fecha_matricula

**estudiante**

- estudiante_id
- estudiante_nombre
- estudiante_apellido

**LO QUE REALMENTE NECESITO ES:**

Que me muestre todas las especialidades y me cuente todas las áreas que estén activas y que hayan estudiantes, no me sirve que me muestre las áreas activas pero sin estudiantes.

Agradecería mucho que me pudieran ayudar.

Comment: Y no puedes agregar una clausula count para los id de estudiantes y un having?

Comment: si fueses mas especifico te agradeceria, en cuanto el having nunca lo he manejado

Comment: que bd utilizas? fijate que marcaste 3 distintas... Having se utiliza para filtrar por una condicion de agrupacion.

Comment: postgresql es lo que estoy manejando, pero hay un problema y es que si cuento los estudiantes y las areas me arrojan los mismo datos

Comment: Recomiendo que si usas varios filtros de búsqueda seas mas especifico, ya que los diferentes Sistemas de gestión de Bases de Datos tienen sintaxis y palabras claves distintas.

Comment: ¿Podrías [editar tu pregunta](http://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/45718/edit), agregar la estructura de las 3 tablas y explicar como se relacionan entre si? Viendo los `INNER JOIN`, pareciera que los nombre de los indices están mal

Comment: listo, la he edita espero que se entienda un poco mejor

Comment: Estás haciendo mal los joins, el especialidad.especialidad_id tendría que ir con especialidad_area_id, estudiante.estudiante_id con area.estudiante_id

Answer (score 1):

Intenta con esto

```
   SELECT 
  especialidad.especialidad_id,
  especialidad.especialidad_descripcion,
  COUNT(areas.*) AS cant,
  COUNT(estudiantes.*) AS cant_estudiantes
FROM
  especialidad
INNER JOIN area ON (especialidad.especialidad_id = area_id)
INNER JOIN estudiantes ON (area_id = estudiantes.estudiantes_id)
WHERE
  area_estado_id = 1 ->(activa)<-
GROUP BY
especialidad.especialidad_descripción
HAVING cant_estudiantes > 0
```

Comment: me dice que no existe la columna cant_estudiantes

Comment: cant_estudiantes lo crea la query como alias.

Comment: si @lithorell eso lo se pero ese es el mensaje que me arroja la base de datos

Comment: Has intentado cambiar el nombre del alias? o revisar si no tienes un error de escritura por ahí? el having debería funcionar

Comment: si, ya lo intente incluso con el alias de las areas(cant) y tampoco

Comment: prueba con HAVING COUNT(estudiantes.*) > 0, me parece que postgress no toma los alias al hacer el having

Comment: lo he intentado es practicamente lo mismo es como si duplicara el count que esta en el SELECT y lo bajara el HAVING